# Why the application crashes when QPushButton::paintEvent is followed by QPainter::fillRect?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am implementing a round button by subclassing `QPushButton` and handling the `paintEvent`. I want to show the text set by the user and then draw a circle.

The application crashes at `QPainter::fillRect` after calling the `QPushButton::paintEvent` method. If `QPushButton::paintEvent` is not called it does not crash, but the button text is not shown.

Here is my code:

```
class CRoundAnimatingBtn : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CRoundAnimatingBtn(QWidget *parent = nullptr)  : QPushButton(parent) {}

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *) { setMask(QRegion(rect(), QRegion::Ellipse)); }
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e) {
        QPainter painter(this);
        QPointF center(width()/2, height()/2);
        QRadialGradient radialGradient(center, qMin(width(), height())/2, center);

        QPushButton::paintEvent(e); // Application crashes if this is called

        if (isDown()) {
            radialGradient.setColorAt(0.0,Qt::transparent);
            radialGradient.setColorAt(0.79, Qt::transparent);
            radialGradient.setColorAt(0.80, Qt::gray);
            radialGradient.setColorAt(0.95, Qt::black);
            radialGradient.setColorAt(0.90, Qt::gray);
            radialGradient.setColorAt(0.91, Qt::transparent);
        } else {
            radialGradient.setColorAt(0.0,Qt::transparent);
            radialGradient.setColorAt(0.84, Qt::transparent);
            radialGradient.setColorAt(0.85, Qt::gray);
            radialGradient.setColorAt(0.90, Qt::black);
            radialGradient.setColorAt(0.95, Qt::gray);
            radialGradient.setColorAt(0.96, Qt::transparent);
        }

        painter.fillRect(rect(), radialGradient); // Application crashes here
    }
};
```

How to fix the crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Cause

You first create a painter, passing a `QPaintDevice *device` to the constructor of `QPainter`, which [calls](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#QPainter-1) `QPainter::begin`:

```
QPainter painter(this);
```

Then you call the base class implementation of
[`paintEvent`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qpushbutton.cpp.html#_ZN11QPushButton10paintEventEP11QPaintEvent):

```
QPushButton::paintEvent(e);
```

which creates a new painter `QStylePainter p` on **the same** paint device, before you are done with the first one:

```
void QPushButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStylePainter p(this);
    QStyleOptionButton option;
    initStyleOption(&option);
    p.drawControl(QStyle::CE_PushButton, option);
}
```

Finally, you try to draw with the first painter `QPainter painter` using:

```
painter.fillRect(rectangle, radialGradient);
```

**Important:** Such approach is not allowed, as the documentation of [`QPainter::begin`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#begin) clearly says:

> Warning: A paint device can only be painted by one painter at a time.

## Solution

Having this in mind, I would suggest you to avoid having two active painters at the same time by moving `QPushButton::paintEvent(e);` to the very beginning of `CRoundAnimatingBtn::paintEvent` (before everything else in this event handler).

**Note:** If you put `QPushButton::paintEvent(e);` at the very end of `CRoundAnimatingBtn::paintEvent`, the default implementation will overpaint your custom drawing and it would not be visible.

## Example

Here is how the `CRoundAnimatingBtn::paintEvent` might look like:

```
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e) {
        QPushButton::paintEvent(e);

        QPainter painter(this);
        QPointF center(width()/2, height()/2);
        QRadialGradient radialGradient(center, qMin(width(), height())/2, center);

        ...

        painter.fillRect(rect(), radialGradient);
    }
```

The example produces the following result:

[image: Window with a round highlighted button]

As you see, the text is shown together with your custom drawing.